# Binding data from view to ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have been developing my first MVVM WPF application, in which I want to draw a graph containing nodes and edges. Currently I am doing all drawing logic in the code behind of my view, iterating over the nodes, creating shapes accordingly and adding them to a canvas.

Because I do not want to keep track of the shapes, and just want them to be drawn based on the data that is given (i.e. the nodes) I have decided to create an `ObservableCollection` of both the `Nodes` and `Edges`, and bind an `ItemsControl` to these in order to automatically draw the shapes.

For now I am focussing on drawing the nodes, and came up with the following XAML code:

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlCanvas" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ?}" ScaleY="{Binding ?}"/>
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Fill="Blue" Width="4" Height="4" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Position.Y}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Position.X}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

In my view, I have two properties `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` which I set when the user scrolls on the canvas. In my earlier code behind version, I would create a `ScaleTransform` with those properties, and apply it to the named canvas using a `LayoutTransform`.

```cs
public partial class GraphOverview : Page
{
    public double ScaleX { get; set; }
    public double ScaleY { get; set; }
```

The problem in this version is that I cannot get around to get it working in my new XAML only code. I would like for the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` attributes of the `ScaleTransform` in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to be bound to the properties in my view. Only, normal `ElementName` binding does not work for some reason. More clearly, the canvas is presumably not aware of the view, I assume because it is a template. Moreover, I cannot call the canvas from the code behind, even when it has a name.

I have tried several solutions, fumbling with `RelativeResources` and the like, but I think I do not clearly understand why a `ItemsPanelTemplate` is so disconnected from everything else in the XAML code. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Maybe I should clarify that this could be easily resolved by moving the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties to the ViewModel, and bind to those properties. But in my opinion such View-specific properties should not reside in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when you say view specific information should not be in the view model. But in your case, the positions becomes part of a model because the positions are nothing but data based on which your view should behave. In such cases you can consider them as part of model rather than view. Write a separate Model Class and use it in the observable collection of your ViewModel Class. I hope it clears your doubt.

```
public class Node
{
    public double ScaleX { get; set; }
    public double ScaleY { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**
Answering your questions. -

*But the Scale properties specify how the Canvas should behave, so does the View not already serve as a 'model' for this? It seems superfluous to me to create a new Model just to set the scale properties of a single Canvas? The view should be merely concerned with drawing data, and since the properties serve as modifications of these drawings, they belong in the View, don't they?*

You want to draw the graph based on the data provided. The Node class is going to provide the data for you. It stores the data and not the logic how the canvas should render, the XAML code uses this data and has the logic to show it in the view.

***so does the View not already serve as a 'model' for this?***

The implementation you have tried has the model in the view, the idea is to separate the model from the view. It might look superfluous initially to create a class just to hold 2 double values. But there are some advantages if you abstract them away from the view.

- In the view model you can create a observable collection for this Node class(Model). You cannot access it from Viewmodel if you have the ScaleX an ScaleY in View.
- In future you might want to change ScaleX and ScaleY to be dervied into different scale e.g. Logarmic scale/ Different unit. In such cases you will have to change the logic in ViewModel to do so and never have to worry about changing the View. But if you have this Observable collection in the view, you have to change the view for making a change to the data/model.
- Lastly - you can write unit tests for whatever you have in the ViewModel but not the View.

Normally ScaleX and ScaleY will be part of the view, but in your case they change and stores data. Hence you need to abstract this ScaleX and ScaleY into a different layer for preserving the MVVM concept.

Comment: But the Scale properties specify how the Canvas should behave, so does the View not already serve as a 'model' for this? It seems superfluous to me to create a new Model just to set the scale properties of a single Canvas? The view should be merely concerned with drawing data, and since the properties serve as modifications of these drawings, they belong in the View, don't they?

Comment: Thanks for further explaining your answer. You have some good arguments, and will use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have set the DataContext of your view, it would help to show more of your code behind

```
internal ViewModel viewModel { get; set; }

public View()
{
      DataContext = (viewModel = new ViewModel());
}
```

Are you binding the ObservableCollection to ItemSource of the nodes? I'm not familiar with drawing, but when I've bound to children, I've never achieved results.

But I've only developed about 4 projects utilizing MVVM.

Comment: I can successfully draw the nodes using the `ItemSource` as described in my question. The `Path=Nodes` refers to a `ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes` property inside my `GraphOverview` ViewModel. But the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of which I need the values are present in the code behind of the View itself, not in the ViewModel. Hopefully this clears things up a bit.